# Django lazy load images

Tags: html, django, python-requests, lazy-loading, render

i am working on a Django project, where we built a Bootstrap carousel of images.
My task now is to try and lazy load those images.
How would I write a view in Django and in HTML that would request the next image in the list and the render it.
The carousel does have a back and next button that could be used as an event but I am unsure how I would go about partially rendering the slideshow.

Thanks in advance.